# How to get certains keys of a dictionnary and their values with it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have this function that print keys and their values from a dictionnary that contains words in french and their translations in english.

```
def affiche_dico(dic):
    k_l = list(dic.keys())   #the keys are the french words
    v_l = list(dic.values())   #the values are the translations in english
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(k_l)):
        print(k_l[i], " = ", v_l[i])
```

My question is, how do I print only keys and their corresponding values just for a certain letter. For example if I want only the words that begins by 'a' how do I do that ?

Comment: Will it always be "print keys/values if a word __begins__ with _<some-letter>_" or can the letter be in any position?

Comment: No the letter has to be in the first position. If dic = { 'voiture' : car , 'gâteau' : cake , 'voilier' : ship} let say i want the words that begins with 'v'. I want only voiture = car and voilier = ship to be printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly iterate over dictionary and no need to store key and value to separate list.

```
dic = { 'voiture' : 'car' , 'gâteau' : 'cake' , 'voilier' : 'ship'}

for key, value in dic.items():
    if key[0] == 'v' : # comparing v to the first character of key
        print("{} = {}".format(key,value))


voiture = car
voilier = ship
```

Comment: good :), please accept the answer . https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers